# Test that another component is rendered on button click ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, ui-testing

I have two separate components in two different files

**ComponentA** and **ComponentB**

I have a button in **ComponentB**

Now I wish to test that when a particular button in **ComponentB** is clicked, **ComponentA** should be rendered as below:

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import ComponentA from './ComponentA';
import ComponentB from './ComponentB'

test('Component A Comes up on Click of Component B button', () => {
  render(<ComponentB />);

  const componentBButton = screen.getByRole('button');
  
  fireEvent.click(componentBButton);
  
  expect(<ComponentA />).toBeInTheDocument(); //This throwing an error that receiver must be HTMLElement or SVGElement

});
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error `Receiver must be HTMLElement or SVGElement` on the `expect(<ComponentA />).toBeInTheDocument();` line

Please, I'm new to testing, how can I solve this?
Thank you for your input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UI testing is meant to test the rendered output, not the internal structure of your code. In other words, you **should not** test that *a component* was rendered, but instead you **should** test that *something rendered* by that component is on the screen.

For example, if `ComponentA` renders an `h1` tag with text content "hello world", you would want to test that that tag or text is in the document.

Here's a simplified example.

*ComponentA*

```js
const ComponentA = () => <h1>hello world</h1>
```

*ComponentB*

```js
const ComponentB = () => (
  <div>
    <p>My App</p>
    <ComponentA />
  </div>
);
```

*Test*

```js
test('hello world is rendered to the screen', () => {
  render(<ComponentB />);
  
  // Asserts that the HTML ComponentA produces was actually rendered
  expect(screen.findByText('hello world')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `expect` function can only be a DOM element rather than a React component.

You could check to see if `<ComponentA>` is in the document by identifying it after the `fireEvent.click(componentBButton)` call. Does it have an `id` or any other unique attribute?

Let's imagine below is the definition of `<ComponentA>`:

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  return (
    <div id="component_a">Hello World</div>
  );
}
```

We can now identify it using the `component_a` id and passing that to our `expect` function:

```
expect(document.getElementById("component_a")).toBeInTheDocument();
```